# Visual Studio's text editor dropdown - sort by member type

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 c# Express and visual studio 2010 Shell.

In the upper part of the text editor window there are two drop down menus, one with scope the other with all members of the class.

It lists both functions and variables, is there a way to set the second drop down to lists only methods/functions, or to "sort it by member type" just like it the Class View?

EDITED: Just got info from MS there is no way to filter the navigation bar.

Comment: Yeah this is super annoying, can't believe MS hasn't addressed this yet.

Comment: Yeah, they should also have the size of the dropdown configurable, as it's really annoying when you have a reasonably large monitor, yet you can only see a maximum of 14 rows in that dropdown.